# Every n element of an array in C++

Tags: c++

Are there more efficient methods of getting every second (every N in general) element of an array then the simple for loop below? For example with the use of generic algorithms?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a_size = 6, b_size = 3;
    int a[a_size] = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 7}; 
    int b[b_size];
    int bx = 0;
    for ( int ax = 0; ax < a_size; ++ax )
    {   
        if (ax % 2 == 0)
            b[bx++] = a[ax];  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Using: `for (int ax = 0; ax < a_size; ax += 2)` or `for (int ax = 0; ax < a_size; ax += N)`.

Comment: Be aware that, in your example, the odd-numbered elements of b are uninitialized values.

Comment: They aren't (the copying is kept track of by `bx`). But if `b_size` is given the wrong value relative to the step (2 in the example), there will be uninitialized values in the destination array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for (int ax = 0; ax < a_size; ax += 2)
```

Just be careful if `a_size` is close to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Just make sure `a_size <= INT_MAX - 2`. But if you have an array with a size near `INT_MAX`, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson - yes, when skipping 2 elements. But the question was more generally about `N` elements.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am going to ask it as a separate question but I need to do this recursively. First time it should skip  n , then 2n, then 4n and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

A loop should be good enough. As Pete pointed out, you can avoid the modulo test.

```
 for (int ax = 0; ax < a_size; ax += 2)
   ...
```

C++ offers support for slicing via the [valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/) header (e.g., take a look at [std::slice_array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/slice_array/)).

I don't know if that is what you are looking for. It is intended for heavyweight numeric computations. If you are unsure, I think the simple loop is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

If by efficient, you mean faster with a smaller memory footprint, then I would opt to use pointers instead of array access. For example, what you want can be implemented in the following way with pointers.

```
int main() {
    const int a_size = 6, b_size = 3;
    int a[a_size] = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 7}; 
    int b[b_size];
    int* a_ptr = a;
    int* a_end_ptr = a_ptr + a_size;
    int* b_ptr = b;
    while(a_ptr < a_end_ptr) {
        *b_ptr = *a_ptr;
        b_ptr++;
        a_ptr += 2;
    }
}
```

This example should be slightly faster than the array access examples and I encourage you to time it and see for yourself. However one thing you should always be aware of when making these optimizations is to look at whether it matters in the large scheme of the program (don't spend time when you don't have to).

Comment: This code is a bug waiting to happen. If `a_size` is an _odd number_ you will increment `a_ptr` past the end of the array and keep going until you crash.

Comment: There is no use at all in writing your complicated pointer code. The compiler automatically puts in those pointers for you anyway, if you turn on optimization. So just plain: `for(int ax=0; ax < a_size; ax += 2) b[bx++] = a[ax]` is enough and in most cases the fastest solution.

Comment: @Kai Petzke, you are also right about compiler optimizing loops to pointers, but I think there is a point about writing explicit code and I don't think compiler optimization should be an excuse to write unoptimized code (if speed and memory is important).

Comment: You can compare pointers that way if they point to elements of the same array, __or one past the last element__. Instead of crashing, your "fixed" code now has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I am not sure what you mean. This code will run fine; `a_ptr` will always reach `a_end_ptr` or move past it. In either case,  it works. I encourage you to compile and run the code yourself.

Comment: You are potentially comparing a pointer __two elements past the end__ of an array. The language standard is clear that the result is undefined. "Works on my machine" is not a compelling argument when the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I now see your argument but I think you misunderstand the standard. There is a difference between comparing the value of the pointer(ie what it is pointing to) and the pointers themselves. when comparing pointers as I have done in the example, it is the same as say comparing integers because they are just hex addresses. What the standard is talking about is looking at the value of the pointer, which will have an undefined value past the array bounds. I hope you understand this key difference, it is very important when working with pointers.

Comment: Sorry, but you are still wrong. You can't _dereference_ a pointer that's one past the end of an array but you can compare it to other pointers to the same array. If the pointer is __two or more__ past the end then the comparison is undefined. The simplest example is that `a_ptr+2` might overflow.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I am not sure I can make you understand what is happening in my example. But if what you are saying is true, then you should be able to prove it by example. So I encourage you to write a loop that runs my example a thousand or a million times to see if there is ever undefined behaviour . I would be interested in the results; if I am wrong, I would like to know.

Comment: I know it will almost always work. Unfortunately, the language standard explicitly only guarantees that a pointer __one past the end__ of an array is valid. Again, I know it will very rarely fail but relying on undefined behavior is a terrible practice.

Comment: Stated another way, if `a_ptr` points one past the end of an array there is no guarantee that adding an arbitrary offset to `a_ptr` is still a valid address and will compare greater than `a_ptr`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, oh you are saying that even the arithmetic might be undefined. I did not know that; I was under the impression that only dereferencing will a problem. Thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: It's possible to conceive a situation where it might fail but that would be very rare. It's just another case where `C` and `C++` very carefully only specify certain behavior. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create a `every_n` predicate and use that to filter as desired for copy_if, etc. That's as generic as you can get.

Approximate (note: untested as of yet) example of an "every n elements" predicate:

```
/**
 @brief Un predicado que retorna @c true cada @a n invocaciones.
**/
template <typename Integer>
struct every_n {
    static_assert (std::numeric_limits<Integer>::is_integer, "Must behave like an integer");
    public:
    explicit every_n (Integer const& e)
    : n(e), x(1) {}

    every_n (every_n const& E)
    : n(E.n), x(E.x) {}

    bool operator () (...) {
        if (x<n) { ++x; return false; }
        else { x=Integer(1); return true; }
    }

    private:
    Integer x;
    const Integer n;
};

// "make_" idiom
template <typename Integer>
every_n<Integer> every (Integer const& c) { return every_n<Integer>(c); }


// sample usage
# include required headers, etc
using namespace std;
const int a_size = 6, b_size = 3;
int a[a_size] = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 7}; 
int b[b_size];
copy_if (begin(a), end(a), begin(b), every(3));
```

All the code requires is that `every()` is called with a type that behaves like an integer.

(The code uses static_assert, begin(), end() and copy_if(), which are C++11, but functions just as well in C++03 if you backport the adequate functions, as I have)

Comment: I don't understand this (it's too complicated for me). The unary predicate of copy_if takes as argument the array element, not the position of this element. Is it possible to pass element position to predicate?

Comment: It is possible but it doesn't _have_ to. The `every()` call creates a predicate that "ticks" every n times it is called. `copy_if` passes to it an element to test in each step, but the `bool operator()(...)` discards it because the elements _don't matter_, only the count of steps, which the predicate internally keeps track of. When `every_n` "ticks", the element is marked as a positive match for the calling algorithm, no matter its value.

Answer (score 1):

This is as fast as it gets:

```
void copy_n(int & a[], int & b[], int a_sz, int n) {
  int bx = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<a_sz; i+=n) {
    b[bx++]=a[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int a_size = 6;
    const int b_size = a_size / 2;

    int a[a_size] = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 7}; 
    int b[b_size];

    for (int ax = 0, bx = 0; ax < a_size; ax += 2) {
        b[bx++] = a[ax];
    }   
}
```